can't extract message when sending alert to mattermost
Can't receive message column in mattermost alert.
Hi! I'm using graylog for alerting and storing logs.
What I expect:
I want to receive the message column in mattermost as alert. The message column is the column with log information for example:
{"body":{"cardId":"19173","cardParams":{"course_id":"0"},"selectColumns":["Почта","БЮ"]},"params":{},"query":{},"url":"/meta/card/query","baseUrl":""} success

What I tried to do:
I have already set up the event definition properly.
Also I have already set up the event notification with this template
--- [Event Definition] ---------------------------
Title:       ${event_definition_title}
Type:        ${event_definition_type}
--- [Event] --------------------------------------
Alert Replay:         ${http_external_uri}alerts/${event.id}/replay-search
Timestamp:            ${event.timestamp}
Message:              ${event.message}
Source:               ${event.source}
Key:                  ${event.key}
Priority:             ${event.priority}
Alert:                ${event.alert}
Timestamp Processing: ${event.timestamp}
Timerange Start:      ${event.timerange_start}
Timerange End:        ${event.timerange_end}
Event Fields:
${foreach event.fields field}
${field.key}: ${field.value}
${end}
${if backlog}
--- [Backlog] ------------------------------------
Last messages accounting for this alert:
${foreach backlog message}
${message.timestamp}  ::  ${message.source}  ::  ${message.message}
${message.message}
${end}${end}

What actually happpend:
I receive alerts like this
--- [Event Definition] ---------------------------
Title:       glpi-sync
Type:        aggregation-v1
--- [Event] --------------------------------------
Timestamp:            2024-11-28T09:36:33.408Z
Message:              glpi-sync
Source:               graylog
Key:
Priority:             2
Alert:                true
Timestamp Processing: 2024-11-28T09:36:33.408Z
Timerange Start:
Timerange End:
Event Fields:

I want to receive alerts with messages to understand what happend. What should I do?
